# How to add a button pro-grammatically in VBA that points to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a VBA program that will add a button in column C that will send you to the sheet on the same row. I would like the button to be in the cell in column C that corresponds to the sheet name. The name of the sheets is in Column A.

Here is an example of the data that I have:

[image]

My actual data has a lot more sheets which is why I think a program would be best.

Any help would be appreciated,

Best

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just hyperlink column A to the relevant sheet? In any event, this is not a code writing site, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, a hyperlink, or the HYPERLINK function `=HYPERLINK("#'"&A2&"'!A1",A2)` which could be copied down the column.

Comment: Andy G, your code works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try somethink like this :

```
Sub addBtn()
      Dim btn As Button
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
      Dim t As Range
      For i = 1 To 5000 Step 1
        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3))
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With btn
          .OnAction = Worksheets("A"&i).Value.Activate
          .Caption = "Btn " & i
          .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A"&i)
        End With
      Next i
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving me runtime error 9: script out of range. I wonder if the first row is messing it up as it is not a sheet.

Comment: For i = 1 To 5000 was an example , change to your last Row or detect last row like this :

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 1):

Try This - it will not add a button, but it will hyperlink the text in each column to its corresponding worksheet

```
Sub HyperLinks()
        Dim ListSheet As Worksheet
        Dim Sht As Worksheet
        Dim row As Integer
        Set ListSheet = Worksheets("List")
        ListSheet.UsedRange.Delete
        row = 1
        For Each Sht In Worksheets
           ' Debug.Print wks.Name
            Sht.HyperLinks.Add ListSheet.Cells(row, 1), "", Sht.Name & "!A1", , Sht.Name
            row = row + 1
        Next Sht
    End Sub
```